# Terraform aws: tag volumes in aws_autoscaling_group

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I started to tag all volumes we create for instances (root and extra devices).
I have found that for **aws_instance** resource I add the **volume_tags** field and all volumes attached for that instace are tagged correctly.

But I dont find a way to tag volumes when using **aws_autoscaling_group** and **aws_launch_configuration** resources. The field volume_tags is not supported for those resources.

Do you know I way to workaround this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be an aws limitation: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=122354

Comment: Yeah, to use the python sdk as an example, the api accepts the same params as the aws_launch_configuration for the api: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.create_launch_configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to switch to using launch_templates instead of launch_configurations. Launch Templates allow for propagation of tags to both instances and volumes.